# Ubuntu (20.04) freezes for short periods of time. Not sure where to start looking

Tags: freeze

I updated my Ubuntu from 18 to 20.04 due to freezing issues. Applications freeze for a short period of time and then come back. Im not exactly sure where to start looking for issues and I cant seem to find people with similar issues.

Im running a gtx1060, but even simple applications like Chrome or FireFox 'pause', so im not sure that it's GPU related

Comment: you can take a look in system monitor under resources and get an idea of what the problem might be,please add information about your system like ram-cpu-graphics.